# Active link style in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, css

I'm having some trouble with my main menu on my ASP.NET website. What I want is, when a user clicks on a link, it should change it's color to black and remain black until the user clicks on the other links.

In other words: I want to highlight the selected link.

So far I've got it working using some workaround JavaScript (should consider using jQuery instead I think), but the problem is, that the style dosn't remain on page postback (or so it seems..)

My current javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var last = "none";
    function LinkSelector(link) {
        if (last != "none") {
            document.getElementById(last).className = "NormalLink";
        }
        document.getElementById(link).className = "ActiveLink";
        last = link;
    }
</script>
```

As I wrote, it sure changes the class name when clicked, but dosn't remain that way when the new page is loaded.

Anyone got a workaround on this? :)

Thanks in advance.

All the best,

Bo

Comment: Should also point out that the menu and javascript is on the MasterPage..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, I'll use the ASP:Menu control. It provides a decent amount of control over the menu items in it.

For example, here's a generic method that I dump in a masterpage and run during the initial page hit. This method loops over the menu items in the menu control, and selects the menu item that corresponds to the current URL.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
            SelectMenuItem();
        }
    }

    private void SelectMenuItem() {
            string rawurl = Request.RawUrl.ToLower();

            rawurl = rawurl.Substring(rawurl.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            if (rawurl.IndexOf("?") >= 0)
                rawurl = rawurl.Substring(0, rawurl.IndexOf("?"));

            foreach (MenuItem mi in mnuMain.Items) {
                if (mi.ChildItems.Count == 0) {
                    if (mi.Value == rawurl) {
                        mi.Selected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    foreach (MenuItem cmi in mi.ChildItems) {
                        if (cmi.Value == rawurl) {
                            mi.Selected = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (mi.Selected)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here are a few of the menu items I have in my asp menu control. Note that I use the Value attribute to help me indicate which menu item pertains to the requested URL in the method above.

```
<Items>
  <asp:MenuItem Text="Forms" Value="authorization">
    <asp:MenuItem Text="New Authorization Form" Value="createauthform.aspx" NavigateUrl="~/CreateAuthForm.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Manage My Authorization Forms" Value="myrequests.aspx" NavigateUrl="~/MyRequests.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Audit Attendance Form" Value="auditform.aspx" NavigateUrl="~/AuditForm.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Tax Determination Statement" Value="taxstatement.aspx"  NavigateUrl="~/TaxStatement.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
  </asp:MenuItem>
</Items>
```

Comment: Hi Jagd,

Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to get it right: using the Menu control you are able to set a StaticMenuItemSelected-Foreground="Black" (or something like that) style which are "triggered" when you set mi.Selected = true; in your codebehind, right?

Comment: There are a number of tags that you can use to style the control. The easiest way to style the menu control is to use the Smart Tag (from the Design view) and apply a scheme to it (Smart Tag -> AutoFormat). After applying a scheme to it, flip back to the Source view (the html code), and take a peak at all of the tags that style the menu item. You should see quite a few (StaticSelectedStyle, StaticMenuItemStyle, StaticHoverStyle, etc.).

Comment: Jagd, that's just perfect! It works just as I would like to :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool, it uses the URL. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @bomortensen - I'm glad it works for you! Also, I forgot to mention, the reason I wrote the function above to select a menu item is because the asp menu control will not select the parent menu item if a user clicks on one of its child menu items. For example, assume you have a parent menu item called Cars and it has child menu items called Honda, Ford, Chevy. The user clicks on Chevy and the page redirects to the Chevy page. At this point (if I remember right), the Cars menu item will not be selected on the Chevy page, thus my method to autoselect the parent menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing your "last" variable as a static member of your function, here's [how it's done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript). That way its value will be retained between function calls. I am not sure if it's retained between page loads, but you can test it.

If not, you'll have to somehow instruct ASP to remember the value. Regarding that, I'm as useful as a lump weight.

Comment: littlegreen,

Thanks for your suggestion, will keep myself reminded of the static member function :) Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem this time.