# How to change the value of a passed variable in a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Inside a function, I'd like to change the value of a global variable that is specified by the function's argument.

```
A = 1;
B = 2;
C = 3;

function myFunction(variable) {
    variable += 10;
}

myFunction(A);
myFunction(B);
myFunction(C);
```

I'm looking for these results:

```
console.log(A);   // 11 expected
console.log(B);   // 12 expected
console.log(C);   // 13 expected
```

I can't output the new value via a return statement because it's computed inside the callback function of a post request.

How to achieve this?

Comment: `0 + 10 != 11`!!!

Comment: It's not possible. This is called `shadowing`, that's that your argument is other variable than global, so A in `myFunction` is other that A in `global`

Comment: @DominikMatis technically speaking this is not shadowing: the thing is that JavaScript always pass by value, not by reference.

Comment: Yes, pretty easily: `function myFunction(variable) { window[variable] += 10; } myFunction('A'); myFunction('B'); my Function('C');`

Comment: @Quentin is correct, there is a clue in [the value/reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/673991). But it's buried, and that's more about a language technicality that one might not know to ask for. This question is directed toward a functional need. (As is this [parameter output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3175687/673991) question, though the need is subtly different.) Future searches might usefully lead here, so I'll **vote to reopen.** Better answer:  `A = {value:0}` etc. then in myFunction `variable.value += 10`

Answer (score -5):

It's not possible. This is called `shadowing`, that's that your argument is other variable than global, so A in `myFunction` is other that A in `global`

Maybe trying to run with `apply()` and using `this.variable` inside function would help