# Javascript Initialization Closure

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create javascript closure that will tell me if the function has already been run:

This is what I have so far:

```
function do()
{
   var isInitialized = function()
   {
     var init = false;

     if (init == false)
     {
       init = true;
       return false;
     }

     return init;
   }

   if (!isInitialized())
   {
     // do stuff
   }
}
```

My function isInitialized always evaluates to true.  I'm like 90% sure I'm not setting the internal variable correctly.  How do I fix my code?

Comment: just move the `init` variable definition to `do` function, `isInitialized` doesn't currently close anything from the parent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are objects in JavaScript so they can be assigned properties which provides a convenient mechanism for achieving what you want to do:

```
function doit() {
   if (typeof doit.isInitialized === "undefined") {
     doit.isInitialized = true;
     // do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to change the `do` to something else as `do` is a keyword.

Comment: I thought that but was just copying Mark's naming.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this.  I didn't think to hard about the method name when I was writing my question.

Comment: I know this answer is 9 months old, but hopefully I'll get an answer: Why do you use `doit.isInitialized` and not `this.isInitialized`? Thanks.

Comment: @pilau: because if you just say ‘doit()‘, then ‘this‘ inside the function will be ‘window‘ or the local equivalent of the global namespace.

Comment: @muistooshort I get it now. Then I will have to do this to make it work: `doit.isInitialized.call(doit);`, right?

Comment: @pilau: You'd have to `doit.call(doit)` and that's a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, sorry, this is what I meant. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't use `do` as your function name as [that's a keyword](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.1).

Secondly, you can attach properties right to your function so you don't need a closure or anything like this:

```
function f() {
    if(f.initialized)
        return;
    f.initialized = true;
    console.log('Doing things.');
}
f();
f();
```

That will give you just one "Doing things." in the console.

Demo (run with your JavaScript console open): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QK27D/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fn(){
  if (typeof fn.hasrun!='undefined'){return;}
  fn.hasrun=true;
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `isinitialized`, it'll reset all the variables to default, so `init` will ALWAYS start out false. The values set afterwards are NOT carried over to the next time isInitialiazed is called.

What you want is a 'static' variable, which JS doesn't directly support, but can be simulated as per this answer: [Static variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript)