# Static self member in javascript

Tags: javascript, static, self

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript)

How can i make a static encapsulation with self members in javascript?
such as in php:

```
class bar{
      static public $foo;
      static public function set() {
            self::$foo = 'a';
      }
}
bar::set();
```

In javascript:
    var bar = function () {
          ????????
    }
    bar.set();

Thanks!

Comment: this does not look like javascript, more like php.

Comment: @Qmal This is exactly what OP says: "here is some php code, how to do the same in javascript?"

Answer (score 2):

Simply define them as properties of `bar`.

```
bar.foo = null;
bar.set = function() {
    bar.foo = "a";
}
```

Here's a nice overview:

```
var bar = function() {
    // Private instance variables
    var a = 1;
    // Public instance variables
    this.b = 5;
    // Privileged instance methods
    this.c = function() {
        return a;
    }
};
// Public instance methods
bar.prototype.d = function() {
    return ++this.b;
}

// Public static variables
bar.foo = null;
// Public static methods
bar.set = function() {
    bar.foo = "a";
}
```

Comment: You just copied the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1535687/851498). Vote to close instead of answering, please, it avoids unnecessary duplication.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I started writing this before you posted your comment. You're right though, this is a duplicate.

Comment: My bad then :-) My first comment still applies though.

Comment: I would vote to close, but I don't have that privilege yet. Hopefully others can help with the vote.

Answer (score 0):

Make a closure that creates the object and returns it. Inside the closure you can declare local variables, and they are private to the scope:

```
var bar = (function(){

  var foo;

  return {
    set: function(){
      foo = 'a';
    }
  };

})();

bar.set();
```

Comment: And... what does `new bar()` gives? It looks like OP wants a class-like solution, not how to make private/public variables.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: Aaaaannd... Nothing obviously, as `bar` is not a function. The usage in the question shows that the OP wants something that can be used as an object, what suggests that it should also work as a constructor?

Comment: Well, it's what the "static" term usually means: use a static method defined in a class you can instantiate. I guess your answer has its place, though.