# Javascript static members

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript)

I have a problem with javascript. What I intend to do is to simulate a class named Tooltip. Ex:

```
var Tooltip = function(){
    this.draw = .....;
    /////////// other members and methods

    this.Static = ...; // this one I want to be static }
```

The problem is I can't find a method to declare a static method/member. And I presume that the above way doesn't work. 
Is there any method to simulate a class with a static member? (preferably using object literals)

LE: I forgot to tell that I want to have acces to the static members from an instance of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is a Prototype language.. It's not C

That being said.. Watch some video's of David Crockford and see if [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript) fit's your bill.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, tooltip.sam() will be "sam" and you can't change it.

This is called the "Revealing Module Pattern" I believe.

```
var tooltip = function() {
        var _sam = "sam";


        var sam : function()
           { 
             return _sam;
           }

        return { 
           sam :  sam 
        };
 })();
```

Comment: This is too complex and is not practical, but thanks for the tip.