# What benefits does ES2015 (ES6) `class` syntax provide?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have many question about ES6 classes.

What's the benefit of using `class` syntax? I read that public/private/static will be part of ES7, is that a reason?

Moreover, is `class` a different kind of OOP or it still JavaScript's prototypical inheritance? Can I modify it using `.prototype` ? Or is it just the same object but two different ways to declare it.

Are there speed benefits? Maybe it's easier to maintain/understand if you have a big application like big app?

Comment: Just my own opinion: the newer syntax is much easier to understand and would not require much prior experience (especially since most people will have come from an OOP language). But the prototype object model is worth knowing and you will never learn that using the new syntax, also, it will be more challenging to work on prototype code unless you already know it.

So I would choose to write all my own code with the old syntax when I have that choice

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54861781/855954), particularly the section about features only possible with the class syntax.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The new `class` syntax is mostly, though not entirely, syntactic sugar (but, you know, the *good* kind of sugar). It markedly simplifies writing constructor functions and the objects they assign as prototypes to the objects they create, especially when setting up inheritance hierarchies, which was error-prone with the ES5 syntax. But unlike the old way, `class` syntax also enables `super.example()` for supercalls (which are notoriously hard to do the old way) as well as [property declarations](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), [private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), and [private methods](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods) (including [static ones](http://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features/)).

(Sometimes people say you have to use `class` syntax if you want to subclass `Error` or `Array` [which couldn't be properly subclassed in ES5]. That's not true, you can use a different ES2015 feature, `Reflect.construct` [[spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-reflect.construct), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct)], if you don't want to use `class` syntax.¹)

> Moreover, is `class` a different kind of OOP or it still JavaScript's prototypical inheritance?

It's the same prototypical inheritance we've always had, just with cleaner, more convenient, and less error-prone syntax *if* you like using constructor functions (`new Foo`, etc.), plus some added features.

> Can I modify it using `.prototype`?

Yes, you can still modify the `prototype` object on the class's constructor once you've created the class. E.g., this is perfectly legal:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    test1() {
        console.log("test1: name = " + this.name);
    }
}
Foo.prototype.test2 = function() {
    console.log("test2: name = " + this.name);
};
```

> Are there speed benefits?

By providing a specific idiom for this, I suppose it's *possible* that the engine may be able to do a better job optimizing. But they're awfully good at optimizing already, I wouldn't expect a significant difference. One thing in particular about `class` syntax is that if you use [property declarations](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), you can minimize the number of *shape changes* an object goes through when being constructed, which can make interpreting and later compiling the code a bit faster. But again, it's not going to be big.

> What benefits does ES2015 (ES6) `class` syntax provide?

Briefly: If you don't use constructor functions in the first place, preferring `Object.create` or similar, `class` isn't useful to you.

If you do use constructor functions, there are some benefits to `class`:

- The syntax is simpler and less error-prone.
- It's **much** easier (and again, less error-prone) to set up inheritance hierarchies using the new syntax than with the old.
- `class` defends you from the common error of failing to use `new` with the constructor function (by having the constructor throw an exception).
- Calling the parent prototype's version of a method is much simpler with the new syntax than the old (`super.method()` instead of `ParentConstructor.prototype.method.call(this)` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)).method.call(this)`).
- Property declarations can make the shape of the instances being created clearer, separating it from the constructor logic.
- You can use private fields and methods (both instance and static) with `class` syntax, and not with ES5 syntax.

Here's a syntax comparison (without private members) for a hierarchy:

```
// ***ES2015+**
class Person {
    constructor(first, last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }

    personMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    constructor(first, last, position) {
        super(first, last);
        this.position = position;
    }

    employeeMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
    constructor(first, last, position, department) {
        super(first, last, position);
        this.department = department;
    }

    personMethod() {
        const result = super.personMethod();
        // ...use `result` for something...
        return result;
    }

    managerMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Example:

```js
// ***ES2015+**
class Person {
    constructor(first, last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }

    personMethod() {
        return `Result from personMethod: this.first = ${this.first}, this.last = ${this.last}`;
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    constructor(first, last, position) {
        super(first, last);
        this.position = position;
    }

    personMethod() {
        const result = super.personMethod();
        return result + `, this.position = ${this.position}`;
    }

    employeeMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
    constructor(first, last, position, department) {
        super(first, last, position);
        this.department = department;
    }

    personMethod() {
        const result = super.personMethod();
        return result + `, this.department = ${this.department}`;
    }

    managerMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}

const m = new Manager("Joe", "Bloggs", "Special Projects Manager", "Covert Ops");
console.log(m.personMethod());
```

vs.

```
// **ES5**
var Person = function(first, last) {
    if (!(this instanceof Person)) {
        throw new Error("Person is a constructor function, use new with it");
    }
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
};

Person.prototype.personMethod = function() {
    // ...
};

var Employee = function(first, last, position) {
    if (!(this instanceof Employee)) {
        throw new Error("Employee is a constructor function, use new with it");
    }
    Person.call(this, first, last);
    this.position = position;
};
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;
Employee.prototype.employeeMethod = function() {
    // ...
};

var Manager = function(first, last, position, department) {
    if (!(this instanceof Manager)) {
        throw new Error("Manager is a constructor function, use new with it");
    }
    Employee.call(this, first, last, position);
    this.department = department;
};
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager;
Manager.prototype.personMethod = function() {
    var result = Employee.prototype.personMethod.call(this);
    // ...use `result` for something...
    return result;
};
Manager.prototype.managerMethod = function() {
    // ...
};
```

Live Example:

```js
// **ES5**
var Person = function(first, last) {
    if (!(this instanceof Person)) {
        throw new Error("Person is a constructor function, use new with it");
    }
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
};

Person.prototype.personMethod = function() {
    return "Result from personMethod: this.first = " + this.first + ", this.last = " + this.last;
};

var Employee = function(first, last, position) {
    if (!(this instanceof Employee)) {
        throw new Error("Employee is a constructor function, use new with it");
    }
    Person.call(this, first, last);
    this.position = position;
};
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;
Employee.prototype.personMethod = function() {
    var result = Person.prototype.personMethod.call(this);
    return result + ", this.position = " + this.position;
};
Employee.prototype.employeeMethod = function() {
    // ...
};

var Manager = function(first, last, position, department) {
    if (!(this instanceof Manager)) {
        throw new Error("Manager is a constructor function, use new with it");
    }
    Employee.call(this, first, last, position);
    this.department = department;
};
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager;
Manager.prototype.personMethod = function() {
    var result = Employee.prototype.personMethod.call(this);
    return result + ", this.department = " + this.department;
};
Manager.prototype.managerMethod = function() {
    // ...
};        

var m = new Manager("Joe", "Bloggs", "Special Projects Manager", "Covert Ops");
console.log(m.personMethod());
```

As you can see, there's lots of repeated and verbose stuff there which is easy to get wrong and boring to retype (I used to use a script for it, back in the day, before `class` came along).

I should note that in the ES2015 code, the `Person` function is the prototype of the `Employee` function, but that's not true in the ES5 code. In ES5, there's no way to do that; all functions use `Function.prototype` as their prototype. Some environments supported a `__proto__` pseudo-property that might have allowed changing that, though. In those environments, you could do this:

```
Employee.__proto__ = Person; // Was non-standard in ES5
```

If for some reason you wanted to do this with `function` syntax instead of `class` in an ES2015+ environment, you'd use the standard `Object.setPrototypeOf` instead:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(Employee, Person); // Standard ES2015+
```

But I can't see any strong motivation for using the old syntax in an ES2015+ environment (other than to experiment with understanding how the plumbing works).

(ES2015 also defines a [`__proto__` accessor property](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__) that is a wrapper for `Object.setPrototypeOf` and `Object.getPrototypeOf` so that code in those non-standard environments becomes standard, but it's only defined for legacy code and is "normative optional" meaning an environment is not required to provide it.)

---

¹ Here's how you'd use `Reflect.construct` to subclass `Error` (for instance) if you didn't want to use `class` syntax:

```js
// Creating an Error subclass:
function MyError(...args) {
  return Reflect.construct(Error, args, this.constructor);
}
MyError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
MyError.prototype.constructor = MyError;
MyError.prototype.myMethod = function() {
  console.log(this.message);
};

// Example use:
function outer() {
  function inner() {
    const e = new MyError("foo");
    console.log("Callng e.myMethod():");
    e.myMethod();
    console.log(`e instanceof MyError? ${e instanceof MyError}`);
    console.log(`e instanceof Error? ${e instanceof Error}`);
    throw e;
  }
  inner();
}
outer();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a fair comparison. You can achieve a similar object without all of the cruft. It uses the JS way of object linking through prototype chains rather than approximating classical inheritance. I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/JasonCust/54d08295d8e678f338fc) showing a simple example based off yours to show to do this.

Comment: @JasonCust: Yes, it's a fair comparison, because I'm showing the ES5 way to do what ES6 does with `class`. JavaScript is flexible enough that you don't have to use constructor functions if you don't want to, which is what you're doing, but that's *different* from `class` -- the whole point of `class` is simplify pseudo-classical inheritance in JavaScript.

Comment: @JasonCust: Separately, there's no much in it in terms of cruft (22 lines vs. 19 if you do apples-to-apples), **but** in your gist, you lose the logic reuse within the `Person` and `Employee` constructors. To get that back, you'd need builders, which would make it longer.

Comment: I guess I could have worded it better but I wasn't implying this was a way of representing classes but showing how an object can be created from object linking that achieves a similar result while also being the more native way in JS. @kyle-simpson sums it up much better than I can in his book [**You Don't Know JS: *this* & Object Protoypes**](http://amzn.to/1dSd2tW), specifically [chapter 6](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch6.md).

Comment: In the end it's simply a different approach that, at least for me, is more straightforward in understanding how properties are mapped up the prototype chain. As far as constructors (or builders), I guess I look at those as more a convenience function that can be added and called from a linked object as needed.

Comment: @JasonCust: Yes, it's a different way. I wouldn't call it "more native" (I know Kyle does, but that's Kyle). Constructor functions are fundamental to JavaScript, look at all the built-in types (except that the anti-constructor faction somehow managed to get `Symbol` messed up). But the great thing, again, is that if you don't want to use them, you don't have to. I find in my work that constructor functions make sense in many places and the semantics of `new` improve clarity; and `Object.create` makes sense in many other places, esp. facade situations. They're complementary. :-)

Comment: Great explanation. I love the last example you gave showing how much more complicated it is to setup an inheritance hierarchy without es6 classes.

Comment: I was sceptical of classes in javascript, now seeing this, I can see that for inheritance, it's much easier to do now. Though for ES7, what's going to be the benefit of the public/private/static?

Comment: @JemiloII: ES7 (more formally ES2016) [is out](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html) and does not have private members, or indeed much of anything else. (public and "static" -- e.g., attached to the constructor -- are of course already there.) There's a [proposal for private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields), currently only at Stage 1, so unlikely to make ES2017 (but it could if it advanced quickly from here).

Comment: meh. I don't buy the need for this. I stepped away from c# to get away from oop and now oop is creeping on javascript. I don't like types. everything should be a var/object/function. that's it. no more extraneous keywords. and inheritance is a scam. if you want to see a good fight between types and nontypes. take a look at soap vs rest. and we all know who won that.

Comment: @foreyez: `class` syntax doesn't make JavaScript any more typed than it was before. As I said in the answer, it's mostly just (much) simpler syntax for what was already there. There was absolutely a need for that, people were constantly getting the old syntax wrong. It also doesn't mean you have to use inheritance anymore than you did before. (And of course, if you never set up "classes" with the old syntax, there's no need to do so with the new syntax, either.)

Answer (score 26):

ES6 classes are syntactic sugar for the prototypical class system we use today. They make your code more concise and self-documenting, which is reason enough to use them (in my opinion).

Using Babel to transpile this ES6 class:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this._bar = bar;
  }

  getBar() {
    return this._bar;
  }
}
```

will give you something like:

```
var Foo = (function () {
  function Foo(bar) {    
    this._bar = bar;
  }

  Foo.prototype.getBar = function () {
    return this._bar;
  }

  return Foo;
})();
```

The second version isn't much more complicated, it is more code to maintain. When you get inheritance involved, those patterns become even more complicated.

Because the classes compile down to the same prototypical patterns we've been using, you can do the same prototype manipulation on them. That includes adding methods and the like at runtime, accessing methods on `Foo.prototype.getBar`, etc.

There is some basic support for privacy in ES6 today, although it's based on not exporting the objects you don't want accessible. For example, you can:

```
const BAR_NAME = 'bar';

export default class Foo {
  static get name() {
    return BAR_NAME;
  }
}
```

and `BAR_NAME` will not be available for other modules to reference directly.

A lot of libraries have tried to support or solve this, like Backbone with their `extends` helper that takes an unvalidated hash of method-like functions and properties, but there's no consist system for exposing prototypical inheritance that doesn't involve mucking around with the prototype.

As JS code becomes more complicated and codebases larger, we've started to evolve a lot of patterns to handle things like inheritance and modules. The IIFE used to create a private scope for modules has a lot of braces and parens; missing one of those can result in a valid script that does something entirely different (skipping the semicolon after a module can pass the next module to it as a parameter, which is rarely good).

tl;dr: it's sugar for what we already do and makes your intent clear in code.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 classes are syntactical sugar on top of constructors that were already there in javascript. Having syntax and semantics which are similar to what we have in other languages, allows programmers to shift from other languages and understand syntax more easily. Below is how a class created as per es6 classes:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  getArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

In other languages like java and c++, You might have seen the concept of static properties and methods. This is how you will do it now in javascript with new syntax:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  getArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }

  static side() {
    return "This shape have four sides";
  }
}
```

And this is how you declare private fields with this new syntax:

```
class Base {
  #privateField1 = 26;
  #privateField2;

  constructor(val) {
    this.#privateField2 = val;
  }

  getprivateField2() {
    return this.#privateField2;
  }
}

let main = () => {
  let obj = new Base(27);
  console.log(`Private field 2 using getter : ${obj.getprivateField2()}`);
};
```

Keep in mind that all of this underneath is still constructors. This new just makes it easy to relate to how programmers've been doing things in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The class syntax is more than just syntactic sugar in one key respect: private variables.

I'll grab a bit of js from one of the other examples.

```js
var Foo = (function () {
  function Foo(bar) {    
    this._bar = bar;
  }

  Foo.prototype.getBar = function () {
    return this._bar;
  }

  return Foo;
})();

//similar to
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this._bar = bar;
  }

  getBar() {
    return this._bar;
  }
}
```

Note the `_bar`.  This is the idiom denoting that something is private while making it public.  When it was invented there was no way to have a true private variable, not without hiding it in a closure.  The trouble with hiding it in a closure is that it made the variables truly private, so private they couldn't even be seen when the object was logged to the console.  And that is a *MAJOR* drawback.  Making the internal state hard to see hinders development.

A long time ago I dropped the underscore prefix for private vars and just started making all vars public.  I had zero issue with this approach because as a matter of discipline I always treat all vars as private.  They can only be accessed via a method of the owning object to preserve the benefits of encapsulation.  Making them public made them easy to interrogate during an interactive development/debugging session.

That is where Class privates save the day.

```js
class Foo {
  #bar;

  constructor(bar) {
    this.#bar = bar;
  }

  getBar() {
    return #.bar;
  }
}
```

These vars can be readily observed by the developer from the console.  But they are actually private, not faux private.  So encapsulation is preserved and so is developer transparency.  And that's more than just syntactic sugar.  You don't get that with the other approaches.