# Using object literal for prototype classes

Tags: javascript, class, object-literal

I'm writing some JavaScript classes (**old school and NOT using ES2015/ES6 and I don't want to use Babel or other transpilers**) and I have one that inherits from the other, overriding one of the parent methods.

So I have my initial `App.Hello` class:

```
var App = {};
App.Hello = function(args) {
    this.name = args.name;
}
App.Hello.prototype = {
    constructor: App.Hello,
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log('Hello, ' + this.name);
    },
    sayGoodbye: function() {
        console.log('Goodbye, ', this.name);
    }
}
```

An then my `App.Yo` class which inherits from it:

```
// inherits from App.Hello
App.Yo = function(args) {
    App.Hello.call(this, args);
}
App.Yo.prototype = Object.create(App.Hello.prototype);
App.Yo.prototype = { // want to combine this with above!
    constructor: App.Yo,
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log('Yo, ', this.name);
    }
}
```

However because I'm using Object literal structure I overwrite the prototype of `App.Yo` when I pass it the `constructor` and `sayHello` methods after setting the `Object.create`. So I don't inherit the sayGoodby method from `App.Hello`

**1. How can I get around this but using literal structure?**

I know I could just do:

```
App.Yo.prototype = Object.create(App.Hello.prototype);
App.Yo.prototype.constructor = App.Yo;
App.Yo.prototype.sayHello = function sayHello() {
    console.log('Yo, ', this.name);
}
```

But I want to keep the literal structure as my classes are going to have a lot of different methods in them. So want to keep it nice and tidy.

**2. Is it possible to nest the complete class as a literal?** So have the constructors as well nested as part of a literal?

e.g.

```
App.Hello = function(args) {
    this.name = args.name;
}
```

and

```
App.Yo = function(args) {
    App.Hello.call(this, args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How can I get around this but using literal structure?

Use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which was added in ES2015 but which can be polyfilled so you don't have to transpile:

```
App.Yo.prototype = Object.assign(Object.create(App.Hello.prototype), {
    constructor: App.Yo,
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log('Yo, ', this.name);
    }
});
```

Or if you don't want to polyfill, just use your own helper, like the standard `extend` function (jQuery has one called `$.extend`, as do many other utility libraries):

```
function extend(target) {
    var i, source;
    for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        source = arguments[i];
        Object.keys(source).forEach(function(name) {
            target[name] = source[name];
        });
    }
    return target;
}

App.Yo.prototype = extend(Object.create(App.Hello.prototype), {
    constructor: App.Yo,
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log('Yo, ', this.name);
    }
});
```

> 2. Is it possible to nest the complete class as a literal?

Yes, by going further with helper functions. For instance:

```
function derive(base, props) {
    var cls = function() {
        return base.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    cls.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);
    Object.assign(cls.prototype, props); // Or use your `extend` here
    return cls;
}

App.Yo = derive(App.Hello, {
    constructor: App.Yo,
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log('Yo, ', this.name);
    }
});
```

Of course, there are a lot of features missing from that, like controlling which arguments you use in `Yo` vs. passing on to `Hello`.

If you want to explore this further, you can look at my [`Lineage` library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lineagejs/), which makes creating classes in ES5 and earlier fairly simple and declarative. Personally, I consider it obsolete because of ES2015 and transpiling, but you've said you don't want to use a transpiler...