# Inheritance in Javascript function error

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I apply inheritance in JavaScript in following way:

```js
var employee = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
employee.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}
var pEmployee = function(salary) {
  this.salary = salary;
}
pEmployee.prototype.getSalary = function() {
  return this.salary;
}

var employee = new employee("mark");
pEmployee.prototype = employee;
var pe = new pEmployee(5000);
console.log(pe.getName());
console.log(pe.getSalary());
```

but it showing following error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: pe.getSalary is not a function

Could any one tell me what's the reason behind this error?

Answer (score 6):

It's because you've added `getSalary` to the object `pEmployee.prototype` refers to, but then **completely replaced** `pEmployee.prototype` with a new object. So naturally the new object doesn't have `getSalary`.

What you've shown isn't the correct way to set up inheritance in ES5 and earlier. Instead, see inline comments:

```js
var Employee = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};
Employee.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
};

var PEmployee = function(name, salary) {
  // Note call to superclass
  Employee.call(this, name);
  // Now this level's initialization
  this.salary = salary;
};

// This sets up inheritance between PEmployee.prototype and
// Employee prototype (then fixes up the
// constructor property)
PEmployee.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
PEmployee.prototype.constructor = PEmployee;

// NOW you add the method
PEmployee.prototype.getSalary = function() {
  return this.salary;
};

// Usage
var employee = new Employee();
var pe = new PEmployee("Mark", 5000);
console.log(pe.getName());
console.log(pe.getSalary());
```

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783217/why-should-i-use-es6-classes/30783368#30783368) for a more thorough example, and also what it would look like if you used ES2015's `class` syntax instead.