# Accessing this inside super() method - javascript

Tags: javascript

The code is as follows

```
class ComposerForm extends BaseForm {
  constructor(formsObject, options) {
    super({
      ...options,
      setup: {},
    });
    this.formsObject = { ...formsObject };
  }
  ..
}
```

Now i have a new form

```
class PreferencesForm extends ComposerForm {
  constructor(company, options = {}) {
    super(
      {
        upids: new UpidsForm(company).initialize(),
        featureSettings: new FeatureSettingsForm(company)
      },
      options
    );
  }
}
```

When initialising the FeatureSettingsForm, i need to pass the Preference form  along with the company object

Something like

```
  {
    featureSettings: new FeatureSettingsForm(company, {prefForm: this})
  },
```

**so that i can access the preference form inside featureSettings form.**

But this cannot be done since **this** cannot be accessed  inside the **super** method.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you tried that and it didn't work? It's true you can't use `this` before you call `super` (so you can't use it in the arguments you pass `super`, since that's "before"), but it would be useful to see the actual failing code in order to help.

Comment: Can we please see the `BaseForm` implementation, especially how it handles/processes `options`. And does `FeatureSettingsForm` also `extend BaseForm`? Depending on this information a solution might be even easier than expected.

Comment: It is merely a sophisticated guess. But from looking into the available code, how the passed arguments get handled, mainly by destructuring (assignments) , how about then writing within the super call something like ... `{ featureSettings: new FeatureSettingsForm(company, {prefForm: null}) }` ... and after the super call, still within the constructor function, something like that ... `this.prefForm = this` ... or anything similar which does target the most probably public availabe `prefForm` property.

Comment: @prajeesh ... alive?

Comment: The scenario is same as mentioned by tj crowder. I have modified the form accordingly so that i don't have to pass this inside FeatureSettingsForm

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right,

- You need to pass a `FeatureSettingsForm` instance in the object you're passing to `super` (`ComposerForm`) in the `PreferencesForm` constructor, and
- You need `this` in order to create the `FeatureSettingsForm` instance

So you have a circular situation there, to do X you need Y but to do Y you need X.

If that summary is correct, you'll have to¹ change the `ComposerForm` constructor so that it allows calling it without the `FeatureSettingsForm` instance, and add a way to provide the `FeatureSettingsForm` instance later, (by assigning to a property or calling a method) once the constructor has finished, so you can access `this`.

---

¹ *"...you'll have to..."* Okay, technically there's a way around it where you could get `this` before calling the `ComposerForm` constructor, by falling back to ES5-level ways of creating "classes" rather than using `class` syntax. But it general, it's not best practice (`FeatureSettingsForm` may expect the instance to be fully ready) and there are downsides to have semi-initialized instances (that's why `class` syntax disallows this), so if you can do the refactoring above instead, that would be better. (If you want to do the ES5 thing anyway, [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783368/157247) shows an example of `class` compared to the near-equivalent ES5 syntax.)