# What the difference between prototype of the class N and class N itself in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, decorator, prototype-chain

Before marking my question as a duplicate of "What is the prototype is JavaScript?" please note that this question is focused on the prototypes of the ES6 classes. Although the prototype chain conception is involved, the implementations of the inheritance mechanism at ES5- are off-topic.

Unfortunately, the general explanation about [inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) does not give a clear answer to my question. Contrariwise, it creates new questions.

I did not care about prototypes of the classes until not tried to create the decorator (on the non-static class property). In the case of non-static class property fields, the first parameter of the decorator function is the prototype of the target class.

From the viewpoint of general explanation, the prototype of the target class is completely useless (at least I don't understand what to do with it even know that this prototype is related to some class) - what is seems to be valuable is the class itself.

```
export function VueReactiveField(
  classPrototype: unknown, // What it this? What we can do with it? 
  fieldName: string
): void {
}
```

Moreover, the prototype has doubled the complexity. If this equation we have for variables now:

1. Target class (everything is clear)
2. The instance of the target class (everything is clear)
3. The prototype of the target class (I don't understand its essence)
4. The prototype of an instance of the target class (I don't understand its essence)

Comment: Are you talking about `targetClass.prototype` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(targetClass)`? I understand you're confused, but it's quite clear about what.

Comment: _“please note that this question is focused on the protoypes of the ES6 classes”_ — They are just syntactic sugar for prototypal inheritance, and the workings of the `prototype` property and the prototype are identical. The `prototype` property points to the object that gets used as the closest link in the prototype chain of each instance other than the instance itself. It is an instance of the super class. _“The prototype of target class”_ isn’t that useful as the prototype of every class just has `Function` in its prototype chain, meaning that every class is a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `class`, primarily, is just syntax for building constructor functions and the objects they assign as prototypes to instances. It's not a different kind of prototypical inheritance from constructor functions. It's a different way of *writing* those. (Plus there are now some features in `class` syntax that are not available if you write constructor functions the old way, such as private fields.) I cover that part of things in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783217/what-benefits-does-es2015-es6-class-syntax-provide/30783368#30783368).

**Usually** when someone says "the prototype of class X," they mean the object on the property `X.prototype`. That phrase is arguably not quite correct (or at least slightly imprecise), but it's common.

Let's say you have:

```
class Parent {
}
class Child extends Parent {
}
```

That sets up **two** inheritance relationships:

1. The `Child.prototype` object inherits from `Parent.prototype`. That way, `Child.prototype` inherits the prototypical properties (if any) and methods (much more common) that `Parent.prototype` provides.
2. The `Child` **function** inherits from the `Parent` function (yes, really). That way, `Child` inherits any static features `Parent` defines.

E.g.:

```
Child.prototype −−−−> Parent.prototype −−−−> Object.prototype

Child −−−−−−−−−−−−−−> Parent −−−−−−−−−−−−−−> Function.prototype
```

Example:

```js
class Parent {
    parentInstanceMethod() {}
    
    static parentStaticMethod() {}
}
class Child extends Parent {
}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Child.prototype) === Parent.prototype); // true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Child) === Parent);                     // true
console.log(typeof Child.prototype.parentInstanceMethod);                 // "function"
console.log(typeof Child.parentStaticMethod);                             // "function"
```

> What the difference between prototype of the class N and class N itself in ECMAScript?

It depends on whether you mean the object on `N.prototype` or the actual prototype of the `N` function.

- If you mean `N.prototype`: `N` is a constructor function, but `N.prototype` is the object that will be assigned as the prototype of *instances* of `N` created via `new N`.
- If you mean the actual prototype of `N`: `N` is a constructor function, but its prototype is the class constructor that it derives from (or `Function.prototype`, if it's a base class).