# Accessing parent prototype method via child object like a normal child method

Tags: javascript

It seems like I don't understand prototypes correctly once again.

If you call a method on an object, and it doesn't exist - does it not check the prototype for the method can run it?

like

```
Array.prototype.myArrayMagic = function () { ... }
```

Then on any array you can call arr.myArrayMagic() ?

That was my understanding, but I am now running into issue where calling a prototype method wont work unless I explicitly call it through .prototype

**Also: I am restricted to ES5 code**

The base module setup

```
function Wall() {}

Wall.prototype = {

    shouldShowWall: function() {
        return true;
    },

    show: function () {
        if (!this.shouldShowWall()) {
            return;
        }

        // Do other stuff here
    }
}

module.exports = Wall;
```

The child object

```
function OtherWall() {
    this.item = 'my_tracking_id',
    this.minutes = 30
    // ...
}

OtherWall.prototype = {
    constructor: Object.create(Wall.prototype),

    /**
     * Override wall.prototype.shouldShowWall method for deciding if the wall should be shown at this time
     */
    shouldShowWall: function() {
        // return true or flase here
    }.bind(this)
}

module.exports = OtherWall;
```

So following other answers and trying to understand as best as possible, this should be set up in a way where I can call

```
new OtherWall().show();
```

but it doesn't work, it only works if I call

```
new OtherWall().prototype.show();
```

Is this normal, or have I set it up wrong?

What do I need to change to get it to work with `OtherWall().show();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you call a method on an object, and it doesn't exist - does it not check the prototype for the method can run it?

Yes, it does (like with any property), but this code is incorrect:

```
OtherWall.prototype = {
    constructor: Object.create(Wall.prototype)
    // ...
```

That won't make `Wall.prototype` the prototype of `OtherWall.prototype`. To do that, do this:

```
OtherWall.prototype = Object.create(Wall.prototype);
```

Then add properties on `OtherWall.prototype`, starting with `constructor`:

```
// But keep reading, I wouldn't do it quite like this
OtherWall.prototype.constructor = OtherWall;
```

...then `shouldShowWall`, etc.

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783217/what-benefits-does-es2015-es6-class-syntax-provide/30783368#30783368) may also be useful, it shows creating a "subclass" using ES5 syntax (contrasting it with ES2015's `class` syntax).

Another couple of notes:

1. This looks like it's probably not what you intend:

```
/**
 * Override wall.prototype.shouldShowWall method for deciding if the wall should be shown at this time
 */
shouldShowWall: function() {
    // return true or flase here
}.bind(this)
```

The `this` in scope there isn't an instance of `OtherWall`, it's whatever `this` is outside that object literal. If you want to bind `shouldShowWall` to the instance, you'll need to do that in the constructor.

2. I'd suggest making methods non-enumerable, like ES2015's `class` syntax does, and the same for the `constructor` property like JavaScript always has. When you create a property via simple assignment, the property is enumerable.

3. I think you have a typo in `OtherWall`, you've used a `,` at the end of the first statement instead of a `;`. Technically, it works, because of the comma operator, but I don't think you were using the comma operator on purpose. :-)

Here's an example applying all of the above; `Object.defineProperty` is an ES5 method (I'm out of practice writing ES5 code, but I think I've avoided all ES2015+ stuff here):

```js
function assignNonEnumerable(target, source) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function (key) {
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
            value: source[key],
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            enumerable: false, // This is the default, but showing it here for emphasis
        });
    });
}

function Wall() {
}

assignNonEnumerable(Wall.prototype, {
    shouldShowWall: function () {
        return true;
    },

    show: function () {
        console.log("show called");
        if (!this.shouldShowWall()) {
            return;
        }

        // Do other stuff here
    },
});

function OtherWall() {
    this.item = "my_tracking_id";
    this.minutes = 30;
    // If you want to bind it to the instance:
    this.shouldShowWall = this.shouldShowWall.bind(this);
}

OtherWall.prototype = Object.create(Wall.prototype);
assignNonEnumerable(OtherWall.prototype, {
    constructor: OtherWall,
    shouldShowWall: function () {
        // You can't bind the instance here, see the constructor above
        console.log("shouldShowWall called");
        return Math.random() < 0.5;
    },
});

new OtherWall().show();
```