# Extending ES5 functions (Imitating Vue Composition API with native JS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, scope, closures

I have been using the latest version of Vue.js and I really like the composition API but as I can't use vue for all my projects I have been experimenting with getting a similar syntax with native JS.

I have found that I can emulate es6 classes with the following code with the advantage of a syntax closer to Vue, no need to prefix all my variables with `this`.

```js
function Component (node) {

   const test1 = "I am a private variable"
   this.test2 = "I am a public variable"
      
   getProps = () => {
      return test1; // I am a private method with access to component variables
   }

   onTimeout = (callback) => {
      setTimeout(callback, 1000);
   }
   
};

function Media (node) {
      
   Component.call(this, node); // copies public variables and methods 
   const sup = Object.assign({}, this); // acts like super in es6 classes
   const props = getProps();

   console.log(sup)
   console.log(props)

   onTimeout(() => {
      console.log("I am executed on timeout")
   })
      
}

new Media();
```

While it all seems to be functional and the browser doesn't throw any errors, typescript does not like the `getProps` or `extend` methods and throws the error `Cannot find name 'getProps'`, when trying this code on codesandbox.io it also throws an error `getProps is not defined`.

If you run this code snippet here on stackoverflow it should also work.

While I could prepend `this.` to the methods that would make them public and no long private.

So my questions are:

- is this valid code?
- what exactly is going on here, if it is not valid why does this work in the browser?
- would there be any problem in using this in a production environnement?
- if so is there any other way I could accomplish the same thing?
- if not how do I tell typescript to not generate an error for the 2 methods?

Comment: Why are you limited to ES5?  I believe all the modern browsers are supporting most ES6 syntax at this point...

Comment: `getProps` is an implicit global and a terrible practice. For example, you cannot have two different modules, then since all will share the same `getProps`.

Comment: To get warned of issues like implicit globals, always use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (where they're the error they always should have been).

Comment: This is far too broad and open-ended a question for SO's Q&A format (especially #4), please see the [help].

Comment: @AlexanderNied Sorry I probably wasn't very clear I am not limited to ES6 I am just not a fan of the ES6 class syntax.

Comment: *"is this valid code?"* **Yes**, in that it's syntactically correct (in loose mode) and runs. **No**, in that it doesn't do what you think it does. *"what exactly is going on here, if it is not valid why does this work in the browser?"* That code makes use of closures for private data (that part's fine), but then creates **global** variables called `getProps` and `onTimeout`, overwriting them with updated versions every time `Component` is called. That's almost certainly not what you meant to do. It's also why `Media` can call `getProps`; it's a global, **any** code can call it. ...

Comment: ... More on my old anemic blog: [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *"would there be any problem in using this in a production environnement?"* Yes, subsequent calls to `Component` overwrite the globals created by previous calls.

Comment: @TheSloth - If you don't like `class`, you can use `function` for most of it. [My answer here comparing the two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783368/157247) should help with the syntax. If you want to do pseudo-private stuff and concise syntax even for hierarchies of classes, I did [a library back in the day](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/04/announcing-lineage.html). I'm not recommending it (I'd just either use `class` or not use `new` at all), but it seems in the wheelhouse of what you're trying to do. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you it seems so obvious now you say it. I assumed as JS wasn't giving me an error that it was somehow bound to the function.

Comment: @VLAZ I had no idea implicit globals even existed, it all makes sense now thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248383/discussion-between-the-sloth-and-t-j-crowder).