# Why does Firefox give a syntax error, class is a reserved identifier?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

Opening a file named index.html with the following code on Firefox 43 renders the following error:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
    "use strict";
    class RangeIterator {}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I see the following error in the console:

```
SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier
```

Any idea why I'm getting that error?

Comment: Quick tip: Use this table (https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) to check ES6 features compatibility in browsers, compilers, etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Classes aren't supported in Firefox version < 45 according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Well that was simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [**`Can I Use`**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class) ES6 classes support form 45 version of Firefox. if 45 version also throws same error like `SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier` then its better to convert to ES5.

[image]

---

> Babel is a JavaScript compiler. Use it to Transform `ES6` to `ES5` format [`BABEL JS`](https://babeljs.io/) (or) [`ES6Console`](https://es6console.com/).

[**ES2015 classes**](http://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#classes) « Check the below [`Converted`](https://babeljs.io/repl/) code from `ES6` to `ES5`.

```js
// ES6                              ES5
class Shape {                   "use strict";
  constructor(color) {
    this._color = color;        function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
                                  if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
                                    throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
  }                               }
}                               }
                                var Shape = function Shape(color) {
                                  _classCallCheck(this, Shape);
                                  this._color = color;
                                };
```

@See

- [Difference between function and class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45759444/5081877)
- [Function Hoisting by the JavaScript interpreter’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34995357/5081877)