# Angularjs 2 typescript app permentaly moved

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

[image]

When i run my application it gives me several errors:

the first one is:

> SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier in the class thumbnail

code:

```
const MAXHEIGHT = 170;
const MAXWIDTH = 320;
import {Subcategory} from './subcategory'
//import {Category} from './category'
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'

class Thumbnail {

    width: number;
    height: number;

    constructor(element: HTMLImageElement) {
        this.height = element.height;
        this.width = element.width;
    }

    resize(oImage: HTMLImageElement) {
        var maxWidth = 100; // Max width for the image
        var maxHeight = 100;    // Max height for the image
        var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
        var width = oImage.width;    // Current image width
        var height = oImage.height;  // Current image height

        // Check if the current width is larger than the max
        if (oImage.width > MAXWIDTH) {
            ratio = MAXWIDTH / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
            oImage.width=MAXWIDTH; // Set new width
            oImage.height=height * ratio;  // Scale height based on ratio
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        }

        // Check if current height is larger than max
        if (height > MAXHEIGHT) {
            ratio = MAXHEIGHT / height; // get ratio for scaling image
            oImage.height= MAXHEIGHT;   // Set new height
            oImage.width= width * ratio;    // Scale width based on ratio
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
        }
        // Check if current height is smaller than max
        if (height < MAXHEIGHT) {
            ratio = MAXHEIGHT / height; // get ratio for scaling image
            oImage.height = MAXHEIGHT;   // Set new height
            oImage.width = width * ratio;    // Scale width based on ratio
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
        }
        // Check if the current width is smaller than the max
        if (oImage.width < MAXWIDTH) {
            ratio = MAXWIDTH / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
            oImage.width = MAXWIDTH; // Set new width
            oImage.height = height * ratio;  // Scale height based on ratio
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        }
        document.body.appendChild(oImage);
        console.log(oImage.height);
        console.log(oImage.width);

    }

}; 

window.onload = () => {
    var oImage = new Image();
    var oImage2 = new Image();
    // var category = new Category(1, "string");
    var subcategory = new Subcategory("teste",1,2);
    oImage.src = 'AngularJS.png';
    oImage.setAttribute('class','img-responsive');
    oImage2.src = 'ts.jpg';
    var thumbnail = new Thumbnail(oImage);
    var thumbnail2 = new Thumbnail(oImage2);
    thumbnail.resize(oImage);
    thumbnail2.resize(oImage2);
    console.log(oImage.height);
    console.log(oImage.width);
};
```

The second error is:

> GET http://localhost:51580/app
>
> 301 Moved Permanently

The configuration of angular is:

```
 <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {
            TypeScriptHTMLApp1: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

I already tried to create a folder named app and moved the file for that folder but the error persists. I need help with this, I lost several hours and can't resolve anything. I attach one image with the file structure and another one with the firebug errors. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using keyword as prefix of class name `export`

Comment: give me a same error:SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier
 

class Thumbnail {

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34408959/4933038

Comment: you are using firefox ?

Comment: yes, i am using firefox

Comment: Your plnkr in answer's comments is a mess, really. I would recommend you to start from scratch. I've had my code working in previous versions of firefox using `class` which means your code is not being transpiled, it's being read directly as is in the browser. Follow the tutorial and don't move from there until you have everything working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested by @Eric in comment

Classes aren't supported in Firefox version < 45 according to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Browser_compatibility)
. instead try same use case in the chrome.

posted as answer may helpful to someone.

Comment: in the chrome give me :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word app.js:4
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: onreadystatechange traceur-runtime.js:2
DEPRECATION WARNING: 'enqueueTask' is no longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use addTask/addRepeatingTask/addMicroTask
DEPRECATION WARNING: 'dequeueTask' is no longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use removeTask/removeRepeatingTask/removeMicroTask
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: could you redefine your problem on any plunkr ? this may help me to understand your problem better.

Comment: where you bootstrap your main file ? seems your plunkr is incomplete with few files.

Comment: o need to import bootsrap file

Comment: why so ? how angular2 project can run without bootstarping ? strange

Comment: how i import the file in plunkr?

Comment: simply create a new file and add to the existing plunkr/project and add it to the list of imports.

Comment: haha @FabioSantos i mean to say angular2's `bootstrap` file where we bootstrap out main component or entry point for our app. seems you are new to angular2. the problem is your project did't found `app.js` file may be that's the reason your code is not working.

Comment: yes, i'm try out angularjs 2. the file is in root diorectory, how i tell him that?

Comment: from your plunkr i have created one more plunkr for you which works fine. try using this plunkr to tell me the exact error you got and what you are trying to do. here is plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/xEL1rITGKG7BAXgVwYIN?p=preview

Comment: now i get this errors:
GET http://localhost:51580/app
 
404 Not Found
  2ms 

ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: import requirejs into index.html `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.19/require.js` reuire is a module loader, also i have update my plunkr as per your needs check my plunkr.

Comment: I am using visual studio 201 for web and get the error:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Build: Class 'AppComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'OnInit'. TypeScriptHTMLApp1 D:\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\app\app.component.ts 12 
in the line export class AppComponent implements OnInit

Comment: import `OnInit` before using OnInit method see my plnkr for usage of OnInit

Comment: i do copy paste from your plunkr

Comment: than try removing OnInit. in my system this works witout ny error

Comment: i remove and get this error : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Build: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning. TypeScriptHTMLApp1

Comment: please first clear yourself whats the errors you got then either ask a new question or edit and update the same question. as of comments m too confused with your errors sorry.

Comment: i found the solution in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896227/visual-studio-2015-rc-typescript-experimental-decorators-error