# Storing reusable constant in namespaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, constructor

Please don't point me to [Static variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript)

My question is more specific. I newbie to JS (just read a couple of books, see some screencasts, and read blog articles about monoins/monads in JS) so be patient ))

To storing reusable constants I write such code:

```
function SVGobj(w, h) {
    this.value = document.createElementNS(SVGobj.svgNS, "svg");
    this.value.setAttribute("version", "1.2");
    this.value.setAttribute("width", w);
    this.value.setAttribute("height", h);
}
SVGobj.svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function SVGCircle(cx, cy, r) {
    this.value = document.createElementNS(SVGobj.svgNS, "circle");
    this.value.setAttribute("cx", cx);
    this.value.setAttribute("cy", cy);
    this.value.setAttribute("r", r);
}
```

Above code is working. **SVGCircle** reuse constant **SVGobj.svgNS**.

But I don't understand **SVGobj.svgNS =** expression.
Is that legal use of JS expressions according to JS spec?

Note that such code fail:

```
var SVGobj = {};
SVGobj.svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
function SVGobj(w, h) {
    this.value = document.createElementNS(SVGobj.svgNS, "svg");
    this.value.setAttribute("version", "1.2");
    ...
}
....
```

with error:

```
TypeError: SVGobj.prototype is undefined
```

when I try instantiate **new SVGobj(320, 240);**

Why?

Can I create object by **new** operator but starting from **"var Cls = {};"** expression?

Someone suggest to use:

```
function SVGobj(w, h) {
    if (typeof SVGobj.svgNS == 'undefined' ) {
        SVGobj.svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    }
   ....
}
```

Why use **if** which evaluated each time I create object?? My first example seems more natural to me...

Comment: In comments to http://bsdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/static-variables-in-javascript.html people suggest my first solution...

Comment: `var SVGobj = {};` makes `SVGobj` not a function...

Comment: So any **function SVGobj() {}** definition ignored? Or they must be illegal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I don't understand SVGobj.svgNS = expression. Is that legal use of
>   JS expressions according to JS spec?

Yes it is, the **SVGobj** ist a function and **svgNS** is a property of the function.

> when I try instantiate new SVGobj(320, 240); Why?

Is a Name conflict.

> var SVGobj = {}; 
>   SVGobj.svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

is overridden by:

> function SVGobj(w, h) {
>       this.value = document.createElementNS(SVGobj.svgNS, "svg");
>       this.value.setAttribute("version", "1.2");
>       ... }

Dont forget Javascript is not a ObjectOriented language.

> Can I create object by new operator but starting from "var Cls = {};"
>   expression?

This  expression is equal to ({} is only a short cut)

```
var Cls = new Object();
```

> Why use if which evaluated each time I create object?? My first
>   example seems more natural to me...

The first example is better than the **if** solution, but the code could be cleaner.(but it always can. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for answering to all my questions. +1

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
var SVGobj = {};
SVGobj.svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
function SVGobj(w, h) {
    this.value = document.createElementNS(SVGobj.svgNS, "svg");
    this.value.setAttribute("version", "1.2");
    ...
}
```

You're overriding:

```
var SVGobj = {};
```

With:

```
function SVGobj(w, h) {
```

`SVGobj.svgNS` no longer exists then.

You may want to do something like:

```
SVGobj = function (w, h) {
    this.value = document.createElementNS(this.svgNS, "svg");
    this.value.setAttribute("version", "1.2");
    this.svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

    return {
        svgNS: this.svgNS
    };
};

var o = new SVGobj(100, 100)
console.log(o.svgNS);
// http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
```

Comment: Hm... Never see **return {...}** construction in JS "constructors". What is the trick?

Comment: The trick is that the object returned from `new SVGobj(100, 100)` now also has a property `svgNS`, that refers to the internal `this.svgNS` property.

Comment: Hm... in that case code **console.log(SVGobj.svgNS);** return undefined... (( My goal is to store data in way that it will be reusable by other modules and classes without instantiating SVGobj...