# How do I increment an integer inside a variable, every time that variable is called? Javascript

Tags: javascript, integer, increment

How do I increment an integer inside a variable, every time that variable is called? Javascript.

```
var a=0;

var t=loadXMLDoc("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist="+x[a].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"&api_key=83e386b0ba08735e3dee9b118478e56d&lang=en").getElementsByTagName("bio");

for (i=0;i<20;i++)
{
document.write("<div><button type='button' onclick='document.getElementById("+i+").innerHTML=t[0].getElementsByTagName(\"summary\")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;'>Open Bio</button></div>");
}
```

I'm not sure how I would go about incrementing variable a. I need it to increase by 1 every time variable t is called in the for loop.

When I put all of the code in the for loop I get [object node list] returned so this method is not desired.

Comment: A *variable* is not called.

Comment: What's the problem with a++?

Comment: You really have to put `t` in the loop, otherwise it will only be evaluated once. And why would that change the output, what are you currently getting?

Comment: take a look here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript

Comment: You certainly don't need those brackets around a.

Comment: You could do: var t=loadXMLDoc("first half of URL" + a++ + "second half of URL")

Comment: I have updated the issue above to properly reflect my code. Sorry I was vague before. Bergi - I cannot seem to increment a within the for loop. When I try to put t in the for loop, I can't get it to work and no result is returned.

Comment: You should not put all those into one string. Try to add elements step by step. That way you have much more chance to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit I think I can see your problem now. You will need to put the `loadXMLDoc` statement in the loop (since you want to load 20 different XML files), but you can't assign the result of every call to the same variable `t` - as once the button is clicked, the handler will evaluate `t` and get only the last value.

Instead, use an array:

```
var bios = []; // empty array
for (var i=0; i<20; i++) {
    var artist = x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        doc = loadXMLDoc("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist="+artist+"&api_key=83e386b0ba08735e3dee9b118478e56d&lang=en"),
        bio = doc.getElementsByTagName("bio")[0].getElementsByTagName("summary")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;

     bios[i] = bio; // store it in the array

     document.write("<div><button type='button' onclick='document.getElementById("+i+").innerHTML=bios["+i+"];'>Open Bio</button></div>");
}
```

Of course, while that will work it's a bunch of bad practises, including

- unsecured accessing of DOM nodes/properties. If the xml changes its format, you will get lots of exceptions here. You might be sure now that this never happens, but wrapping `artist` and `bio` in try-catch might not be a bad idea.
- snychronous <s>A</s>jax. One can do better than that.
- loading 20 documents (and that sequentially!) even if you don't need them. It might be worth to try loading each of them only when the respective button is clicked.
- `document.write`
- Inline attribute event handlers
- …and creating them even by JS.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you could define your own getters and setters for the property.

```
var o = {}
o.__defineSetter__('property', function(value) { this._counter = 0; this._holder = value; })
o.__defineGetter__('property', function() { console.log(this._counter++); return this._holder; })
```

The counter would be reset every time o.property is assigned a value

```
o.property = 'Some value'
```

and then increase every time the property is accessed.
So,

```
console.log(o.property)
```

would print

```
0
Some value
```

to the console. And if you do it again, it would print

```
1
Some value
```

Comment: Uh, no. That's overkill, the OP just needs to increment a variable.

Comment: Indeed. After his edit, I can see that I did not understand his question correctly.