# Creating "static" members in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, oop, web, prototype

Is there a way to create "static" members in a JS Object?

```
function Person(){

}

Person.prototype.age = null;
Person.prototype.gender = null;
```

I would like to add personsCount as a static member, is that possible?

Comment: Sure, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. (You don't really mean, "in a JavaScript object"; you mean, "in a **class** of JavaScript objects".)

Comment: Please use the search function on stackoverflow first, i think this is the answer on your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1535687/863641

Comment: @Pointy classes are just objects in JavaScript anyway. (Though I don't think "class" is the right word to use in JavaScript to begin with, but I haven't used prototypes enough to know for sure.)

Comment: @JAB yes I agree; I meant "class" in the more generic, colloquial sense :) The point was that if you've only got one object, the concept of "static member" isn't really meaningful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, just add Person.personsCount without the prototype

Answer (score 4):

Common practise is to make such "static members" properties of the constructor function itself:

```
function Person() {
    Person.count++;
}
Person.count = 0;
```