# Is there any pattern that provide similarities of public static, private and public methods and vars in JS?

Tags: javascript, static, design-patterns, private, public

I'm trying to clone the functionality of a class in JS that has private functions, public functions and static public functions. I know patterns that provides public and private methods and vars for my classes, but I don't know how to add static methods to this patterns (Revealing pattern in most cases). Any lead to achieve this?

Thanks!

Edit:

Ok, I Know how to achieve a static method, but If I using a pattern like this, How could I create an static method?

```
var module = (function() {

return function(selector) {
    var options = {
       selector: selector
    }

    var privateFunction = function() {}
    var publicFunction = function() {}

    return {
       public: publicFunction
    }
}
})();
```

Comment: Read Mozilla's Introduction to OO JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static variables in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

"Static" methods in JavaScript are usually achieved by simply assigning a function to a property of the constructor function object:

```
function MyClass() {} // Constructor
MyClass.staticMethod = function () {};
```