# Translate d3.js JavaScript function to CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, d3.js

Afraid I'm making a simple error in in how I convert this JavaScript to CoffeeScript within a class

In this [original example of a world map](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) we have a function :

```
var quantize = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, .15])
    .range(d3.range(9).map(function(i) { return "q" + i + "-9"; }));
```

This is then called when the map is rendered:

```
.attr("class", function(d) { return quantize(rateById.get(d.id)); })
```

And we are left with something like `class="q8-9` which is what we want.

Converting this to CoffeeScript I have:

```
quantize: ->
  d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, .15])
    .range(d3.range(9).map((i) -> "q" + i + "-9" ))
```

Which I then call like this:

```
.attr("class", (d) => @quantize(rateById.get(d.id)) )
```

However this does't return a value, rather it returns the scale function, leaving me with this:

`class="function scale(x) { return range[Math.max(0, Math.min(i, Math.floor(kx * (x - x0))))]; }"`

I'm sure I'm doing something very simple wrong but can't figure it out.  Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
quantize: ->
  d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, .15])
    .range(d3.range(9).map((i) -> "q" + i + "-9" ))
```

you want

```
quantize : 
  d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, .15])
    .range(d3.range(9).map((i) -> "q" + i + "-9" ))
```

`->` is used when you are defining functions but here you are just calling a function (it just happens to return a function) so its similar to its JavaScript counterpart.

Note: Judging by the fact that you had `: ->` to begin with and `@quantize` which translates to `this.quantize`, it looks like you are storing `quantize` in an object which is great, and is what the code above assumes.  If your code is actually more like the original example you linked to where quantize is just a variable, then you will want `quantize = d3...` and `quantize(rateId.get(d.id))` (without the `@`).

The "Try CoffeeScript" link at the top of the [CoffeeScript site](http://coffeescript.org/) lets you write CoffeeScript and it'll translate to JavaScript as you go which is a great way to learn and understand what gets translated into what.  There are also plugins for browsers available that do this.

Comment: Thanks.  Both your answer and @edi9999's work, so it's a tough call on which to accept!  You correctly inferred that I am storing  quantize in an object so I will go with this one ;-).

Answer (score 3):

In your Javascript Code, quantize contains a value:

```
var quantize = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, .15])
    .range(d3.range(9).map(function(i) { return "q" + i + "-9"; }));
```

But in your CoffeeScript version, quantize is a function:

```
quantize: ->
  d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, .15])
    .range(d3.range(9).map((i) -> "q" + i + "-9" ))
```

You should probably just do:

```
quantize = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, .15])
    .range(d3.range(9).map((i) -> "q" + i + "-9" ))
```

so that quantize remains a function.

You should then remove the @ of the `@quantize`, that translates in Javascript to this.quantize, as quantize seem to be a variable and not a property. [Difference between properties and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript)