# Is it possible for all instances of a function to have access to the same private var?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, private

When I do a closure to have private members like in this example by Douglas Crockford

```
function Container(param) {
  function dec(){
    if (secret > 0) {
      secret -= 1;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  var secret = 3;
  this.service = function(){
    if(dec()){
      return param;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
}
```

Each instance of `Container` will have a private `secret`. What if I wanted **all** the instances of `Container` to share access to the same **private** variable? (there are lots of ways to do this with a public variable of course)

So that a call to **any** instance of `Container` would lower `secret` by 1 and no matter what instance call `this.service` it could be called only 4 times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static variables in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: It is not - my question is much more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the object constructor by using a IIFE and put the secret inside that scope:

```
var Container = (function(){
  var secret = 3;

  return function(param) {
    function dec(){
      if (secret > 0) {
        secret -= 1;
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    this.service = function(){
      if(dec()){
        return param;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    };
  };
})();
```

Comment: So what you basically did is to wrap `Container` in another function so that the returned one will have access to another level of closure?