# Same variable across all Instances of a JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, class, variables, object

Is there a way to create some type of variable that is the same in every instance of a JavaScript Class (no global variables)?

For example:

```
function Class(){
  this.foo = 'bar';
  this.setText = setText;
  this.getText = getText;
}

function setText(value){
  this.foo = value;
}

function getText(){
  alert(this.foo);
}
```

Now I create two instances of the same class like so:

```
var fruit = new Class();
var groceries = new Class();
```

When I change the value of foo in the class fruit I also want it to be changed in groceries.

```
fruit.setText("apple");
fruit.getText(); //alerts apple
groceries.getText(); //SHOULD also alert apple
```

I am creating the instances of a class dynamically, they don't have a clear variable names (fruit, groceries) like in the example.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static variables in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there absolutely is, just use a property on the function itself:

```
Class.text = 'apple'

Class.prototype.getText = function () { return Class.text; }
Class.prototype.setText = function (text) { Class.text = text; }
```

Comment: Considering that `Class` is the `this` inside the function, why not pass `this.text`? ( unless someone's crazy enough to do a `.bind` )

Comment: @GonçaloVieira That isn't true. `this` is not `Class` inside the function, it is an object constructed from `Class`. `this.text` would not work, it would be specific to the object, not shared across all instances of the object.

Comment: @meagar you're right, didn't see it wasn't a `Class.prototype.text`, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, using a closure:

```
var Class = (function () {
    var foo = "bar";

    function Class(){
      this.setText = setText;
      this.getText = getText;
    }

    function setText(value){
      foo = value;
    }

    function getText(){
      alert(foo);
    }

    return Class;
}());

var fruit = new Class();
var groceries = new Class();
```

`foo` in this case would be similar to a private static property, which is not available from the outside.

Comment: This has the downside of being notably more expensive; each time you construct a class, that class gets its own unique set of methods, involving extra processing time and memory for each instance.

Comment: @meagar I just copied the code from OP. He had his class constructed that way. Sure, he should use `prototype`, but that was not the question. So I thought I stick to the essential part, which is the question about static properties.