# Shared value using prototype

Tags: javascript

If prototype are shared by all instances, why it doesn't work?

```
var Module = function(){};

Module.prototype.sharedValue = "value";

var a = new Module();
var b = new Module();

a.sharedValue = "other value";

console.log(b.sharedValue) // it prints 'value' and not 'other value'
```

Comment: Because you're modifying the `sharedValue` of `a` only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static variables in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.sharedValue = 'other value'` assigns the `'other value'` value to the `sharedValue` property of the `a` instance *only*.

The way the prototype chain works, is that property access will look at the object instance for whether it contains a specific property, and if it doesn't find the property, it will traverse up the prototype chain until it either:

1. finds the property and returns the value of that property at whatever level of the prototype
2. doesn't find the property on any of the prototypes and returns `undefined`

You should also note that modifying `a.sharedValue = 'other value'` will not have any affect on `Module.prototype.sharedValue`.

Answer (score 2):

To assign to the prototype, you need to do it explicitly:

```
Module.prototype.sharedValue = "other value";
```

Otherwise it assigns the property to the instance, which masks the value on the prototype.