# javascript - class level property

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

When define a class I want to define a class level property, which is shared by all instance objects, how should I defined it? 
I can think of 2 approach:

- Define on constructor

  After define constructor function, define property on constructor itself,
  format to access:
  **constructor_name.propName**
- Define on prototype

  After define constructor function, define property on constructor's prototype,
  this might be hidden by instance property,
  format to access:
  **obj.propName**

So, which approach is proper? Or there are other solutions?

**Edit:**
I want to know the case When property is string/number, not a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static variables in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yeah, that's why I mention call it by the constructor itself in that case, not by instance,

Comment: Neither is really more proper than the other in general. It depends on the individual use case and whether inheritance, including overrides, makes sense for it (prototype) or not (constructor) -- "*this might be hidden by instance property*" as you mentioned.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Ok, I will try to figure out in practice, I was wondering how extjs implement their complex oo mechanism...

Comment: Following answer may be of help. Has a very detailed explanation for people starting with JavaScript oop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Comment: @HMR Yeah, that's a great one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking a while, I try to give an answer myself.

**Define on constructor:**

> **good part**: it won't be override by instance property which has the same name.
>   **bad part**: it can't be access via instance directly, due to not in the prototype chain,but access via constructor itself.

**Define on prototype:**

> **good part**: it could be access via instance directly.
>   **bad part**: it might be hidden when instance define a property with the same name, and its readonly to instance, because when instance try to modify it, it actually create a new instance property instead of modify the one from prototype.

So, maybe it's more proper to define property that is not a function on constructor itself.
And, because of that decision, to keep sync, the class level property which is function, had better be defined on constructor itself too.

Tip: the method define on prototype (metioned by @isayme), should be viewed as instance method, but not class-level method, even though they are defined on prototype, because usually they will read/write instance property.

Answer (score 1):

Define on `prototype` is proper.

Example:

```
function Foo() {
  this.name = 'Jone';
  this.func1 = function() {
    console.log('func1 print :' + this.name);
  }
}

Foo.prototype.func2 = function() {
  console.log('func2 print :' + this.name);
};

Foo.func3 = function() {
  console.log('func3 print :' + this.name);
}

var f = new Foo();
f.func1();  // func1 print :Jone
f.func2();  // func2 print :Jone
f.func3();  // error, instace f cannot call func3.
```

**func1** is defined in constructor, and instance can call it.

**func2** is defined in prototype, and instance can call it.

the difference between **func1** and **func2** is all instances of **Foo** will **share func2** while each instance of **Foo** has a **separate func1**.

**func3** cannot called by instance of **Foo** bcz **func3** is property of **Foo** not property of instance of **Foo**.

Comment: This is true when property is a function, but it seems a little different when property is a string/number, not a function, can you help to suggest on that too.

Comment: all instances will share properties(including functions and other types) defined in `prototype`, and if any property redefined in `constructor`, the new one will be priorer when accessing the property.

Comment: property on prototype is readonly, instance can't change it directly, so it's not proper.

Comment: In fact, property on prototype is not readonly.
You can check the result in [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tddAm/).

Comment: The primary type age on prototype didn't change, instead it create a new instance property on p1, that's why p2's age is still 0 in your output. But the object type name, if you change the name property directly, it will be the same as age. But when you access property of property this is different, because it's not change the property directly, to the instance it's just reading operation.

Comment: Anyhow, thank you, you have raised some quite fallible concepts.