# How to access a static variable from another script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, static-variables

Sorry for asking such a newbie question. Firstly, I searched it on google but I didn't get the results I want. Secondly, I'm pretty new to scripting and unity. Easy question, How to access a static variable from another script? I want to share data between buttons so it won't restart the score when I press it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: In essence you can find your answer here: [Static variables in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript). Remember UnityScript is basically JavaScript.

Comment: @FunctionR I disagree with both of your statements. First, the guy has said he's new to scripting and thread you linked is very much not for newbies. Second, UnityScript is not "basically JavaScript". The code in the answer on the page you linked is not correct UnityScript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

Class name is: test.java

```
public static int na;
```

You can access another static by doing this:
classname.static

```
test.na;
```

Comment: The file should be called Test.js (capitalized by convention, and .js), but yes, it should work. e.g. Test.na = 2;

Comment: actually that worked for accessing other variables, but it didn't share data. Do you know how to share data like static variables but between scripts? Thanks

Comment: It's basically 4 buttons sharing one score GUIText:
`var targetScript : ChangeSprite;
static var score : int = 0;
var guiScore : GUIText;
function OnMouseDown () {
if(targetScript.spriteRenderer.sprite == targetScript.diamond) {
score += 1;
guiScore.text = "Score: " + score;
} 
}
`

Comment: The 4 buttons code are different so thats the problem. The other codes are basically the same but `if(targetScript.spriteRenderer.sprite == targetScript.otherthings`

Comment: This is basic stuff... Look up Object Oriented Programming and read a few books or tutorials online.

Comment: I said I did search it up but I didn't get the result i want! @Savlon