# Stop function after certain number of clicks on a certain element

Tags: javascript

OK so I am making a reaction tester, and I have a function that makes shapes appear on screen, So what I want is some sort of function were after 5 clicks on a certain element it will end a function. Is there a way of doing that? sorry if its a dumb question, its because I am new to the whole coding...

Comment: What do you mean "end function"? Executing a function after five clicks on a certain element?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that, it's called counting. Use a variable that is incremented on each click.

Comment: use a static variable using a closure to count the number of times a function is executed and if it's greater than, say 5 just return.

Comment: What I mean is I have a div that on each clicks starts a function what i want it to do after 5 clicks on that div stop the function

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
var clickHandler = (function (e) {
   var count = 0;

   return function () {
       count += 1;
       if (count > 5) {
           return;
       }

       // do other stuff here
   }
}());

aDiv.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use global variable which may remain counting on click function

```
<script>
var globalvar = 0;

onclickfunct()
{
globalvar += 1;

if(globalvar == 5)
{
//do my work
}
else
{
//give alert
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: So how would this stop the function?

Comment: you may stop based on variable value, suppose you want 5 click just use if condition and limit it to 5, place your code inside.

Comment: yes, inside if condition you may place your code u want to perform on click

Comment: please tick my answer if you feel it helpful

Answer (score 0):

You Can use static variable to count how many times the object has been clicked.
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript) is how you can create static variable in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind the click event once the counter reaches 5. See the example below

```js
function test(sender) {
  sender.dataset.clicked++;

  console.log("I've been clicked", sender.dataset.clicked);
  
  if (+sender.dataset.clicked === 5) {
    // unbind the event
    sender.onclick = null;
  }
  
  return;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="test(this);" data-clicked="0">click me</div>
```