# In javascript, is it possible to create a modifiable static class variable?

Tags: javascript, class, variables, syntax, static

I am thinking something like this:

```
class T {
    static var A;
    static setA(value) {
        this.A = value;
    }
    static getA(value) {
        return this.A;
    }
}
```

so that it is stored in the class and can be both accessed and updated externally

Comment: how about trying it by yourself ?

Comment: It does not seem to work when I try it, but I am not sure what the syntax would be if it were possible, and have not been able to find anything definitive one way or the other.

Comment: @WesEason [your answers are here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445693/how-do-i-make-a-public-static-field-in-an-es6-class/28454250#28454250)

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand, but it seems like that solution does not allow modification of the statically accessible data

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
class T {}
T.A = 7;
```