# Modifying all members of a class via an instance method

Tags: javascript, prototype

In JavaScript, is it possible to call an instance method on an object that affects all of its siblings?

For example, say I have the following class:

```js
function Thing() {
  this.active = false;
}

Thing.prototype = {
  constructor: Thing,

  activate: function() {
    this.active = true;
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    this.active = false;
  }
  
};
```

Is it possible for me to create an `activateAll`  method that can activate all of the instances of class `Thing`?

I need `this.active` to be an *instance* variable.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript

Comment: It is possible, but you'd have to keep an array of all the live object instances somewhere that you could iterate and call a method on each object of that type. And, you may have a garbage collection problem if you aren't properly removing items from that array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could store all the instances in an array, and iterate them to change their `active` property. However, storing all the instances means they won't be garbage collected, so you will waste memory. And if the array becomes huge, iterating it will be slow.

```js
var Thing = (function() { // Use a closure to hide `instances`
  var instances = [];
  function Thing() {
    this.active = false;
    instances.push(this);
  }
  Thing.prototype.activate = function() {
    this.active = true;
  };
  Thing.prototype.activateAll = function() {
    instances.forEach(function(instance) {
      instance.active = true;
    });
  };
  return Thing;
})();
```

A better way would be defining common default activity and default priority, and an own activity and an own priority for each instance. Then,

- To get the activity of an instance, compare the default priority and the own priority. The greatest decides whether the default activity or the own activity should be returned.
- To set the activity of an instance, update the own activity. If the default activity is greater, increase the own priority.
- To set the activity of all instances, update the default activity and increase the default priority.

```js
var Thing = (function() {
    var defActive = false, /* default activity */
        defPriority = 0; /* default priority */
    /* `defPriority >= ownPriority` will always hold */
    function Thing() {
        var ownActive,
            ownPriority = -1;
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'active', {
            get: function() {
                return defPriority > ownPriority ? defActive : ownActive;
            },
            set: function(val) {
                ownActive = val;
                ownPriority = defPriority;
            }
        });
    }
    Thing.prototype.activate = function() {
        this.active = true;
    };
    Thing.prototype.activateAll = function() {
        defActive = true;
        ++defPriority;
    };
    return Thing;
})();
```

If `activateAll` will be called lots of times and you don't want to increase `defPriority` unnecessarily, you can add a boolean variable to know if some own property reached the default one.

```js
var Thing = (function() {
  var defActive = false, /* default activity */
      defPriority = 0, /* default priority */
      someOwnPriorityReachedDefPriority = false;
  function Thing() {
    var ownActive,
        ownPriority = -1;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'active', {
      get: function() {
        return defPriority > ownPriority ? defActive : ownActive;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        ownActive = val;
        ownPriority = defPriority;
        someOwnPriorityReachedDefPriority = true;
      }
    });
  }
  Thing.prototype.activate = function() {
    this.active = true;
  };
  Thing.prototype.activateAll = function() {
    defActive = true;
    if(someOwnPriorityReachedDefPriority) {
      ++defPriority;
      someOwnPriorityReachedDefPriority = false;
    }
  };
  return Thing;
})();
```

In any case, note that adding that method in the prototype doesn't make much sense. According to the OOP principles, calling a method in a variable should not affect other variables. Instead, consider adding the method to the constructor itself.

A full example could be like this:

```js
var Thing = (function() {
  var defActive = false, /* default activity */
      defPriority = 0, /* default priority */
      someOwnPriorityReachedDefPriority = false;
  function Thing() {
    var ownActive,
        ownPriority = -1;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'active', {
      get: function() {
        return defPriority > ownPriority ? defActive : ownActive;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        ownActive = val;
        ownPriority = defPriority;
        someOwnPriorityReachedDefPriority = true;
      }
    });
  }
  Thing.prototype.activate = function() {
    this.active = true;
  };
  Thing.prototype.deactivate = function() {
    this.active = false;
  };
  Object.defineProperty(Thing, 'activeAll', {
    set: function(val) {
      defActive = val;
      if(someOwnPriorityReachedDefPriority) {
        ++defPriority;
        someOwnPriorityReachedDefPriority = false;
      }
    }
  });
  Thing.activateAll = function() {
    Thing.activeAll = true;
  };
  Thing.deactivateAll = function() {
    Thing.activeAll = false;
  };
  return Thing;
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an `instances` array, like this:

```
var instances = [];
```

Modify `Thing` as follows:

```
function Thing() {
  this.active = false;
  instances[instances.length] = this;
}
```

Implement methods by iterating:

```
function activateAll() {
    for (var index in instances) {
        instances[index].active = true;
    }
}
```

You can generalize this, like follows:

```
function genericOperation(f, p) {
    for (var index in instances) {
        instances[index].f(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be preferable for *instances* to be a property of *Thing*. Also, *for..in* iteration over Array members is not considered a good idea, better to use the built–in *forEach*. And there should be a way to remove members from *instances* too.

Comment: You can define it as a property of Thing. I did not really want to assume anything, the reader of this post should have the freedom of choice. In general it is good to be a property of Thing indeed. Removing elements from instances should be done as simple array element removals and a destructor or some cleaner methods are needed. I do not add these to the answer to keep it simple.