# why static variable not show output?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create static variable and static function .But when I am accessing it it gives me undefined why ?
here is my function

```
  function Shape(){
        this.namev="naven"
        Shape.PIe="3.14";
        Shape.getName=function(){
            return "nveen test shhsd"
        }

    }

    alert(Shape.PIe)
    alert(Shape.getName())
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense for `getName()` to be "static", because surely it should return the name property associated with a particular instance? I'd suggest you find a tutorial about JavaScript's prototype-based inheritance and then consider whether or not adding properties directly to `Shape` is the best way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Shape.getName()` function is not initialized until after `Shape()` has been called the first time (the initialization code is inside of `Shape()`) so thus the `Shape.getName` properties does not exist until `Shape()` is called.

Perhaps what you want is this:

```
// define constructor that should only be called with the new operator
function Shape() {
    this.namev="naven";
}

// define static methods and properties
// that can be used without an instance
Shape.PIe="3.14";
Shape.getName=function(){
    return "nveen test shhsd"
}

// test static methods and properties
alert(Shape.PIe)
alert(Shape.getName())
```

Remember that in Javascript a function is an object that can have it's own properties just like a plain object.  So, in this case you're just using the `Shape` function as an object that you can put static properties or methods on.  But, do not expect to use `this` inside of static methods because they are not connected to any instance.  They are static.

---

If you want instance properties or methods that can uniquely access a Shape object instance, then you would need to create your methods and properties differently (since instance methods or properties are not static).

Comment: what is the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

To create a static variable shared by all instances, you would need to declare it outside of the function declaration, like so:

```js
function Shape() {
    // ...
}

Shape.PIe = "3.14";

alert(Shape.PIe);
```

See this post for more details on how you can "translate" some familiar OOP access concepts into Javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1535687/1079597