# Class static properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the new ES6 Class syntax it is not possible to do

```
class Person {
    this.type = 'person';
```

But if I define the property inside the contructor [it works](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ijuet2ph/):

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) { //class constructor
        this.name = name;
        this.type = 'person';
    }
```

I know the possibility to have properties outside methods [is being discussed](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties) but as of today and what relates to the ES6 specs it is not possible.

Is my solution a correct way to define static properties for the Class (for semantic reasons I defined those properties inside the constructor but it seems to work inside other methods)? Is there a better way?

I was looking at the spec in *[Method Defenition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions)* and found no information about this.

Comment: Depends on how you want to access them. That implementation gives each instance a member named `type` but if you wanted statics more like how C# does them then you'd do something like `Person.type = 'person'`. Then it would only be attached to the class instead of the individual instances.

Comment: @MikeC there are many usecases for such properties, I didn't have a specific in mind. If we extend it [we can still use/change](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ijufl5c6/) that property. My question in more in lines like: _is this ok to do?_, or _is there a more correct way?_ that can be done from inside the Class.

Comment: Then I'd say, yes, that's completely fine. [Although I wouldn't call those "static properties"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1535687/371184). They're "instance properties" or just properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already said, what you are doing is creating an **instance** property. Adding such properties in the constructor is what the constructor is there for. This hasn't changed with ES6.

Answer (score 10):

You can create static getter:

```js
"use strict";

class Person {
  static get type() {
    return 'person'
  }
}

console.log(Person.type) // 'person'
```