# Converting old school javascript entity into ES6 class

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
let initPack = { player: [] };
let Player = function(param) {
  let self = {
    id: param.id,
    x: param.x,
    y: param.y
  }

  self.update = function() {
    self.x += 1;
    self.y += 1;
  }

  self.getInitPack = function() {
    return {
      id: self.id,
       x: self.x,
       y: self.y
    }
  }

  Player.list[self.id] = self;
  initPack.player.push(self.getInitPack());
  return self;
}

Player.list = {};
```

If I want to rewrite this to ES6 classes and put it into a separate file in node.js, such as:

```
module.exports = class Player {
  constructor(param) {
     this.id = param.id;
     this.x = param.x;
     this.y = param.y;
  }

  update() {
     this.x += 1;
     this.y += 1;
  }

  getInitPack() {
    return {
      id: self.id,
       x: this.x,
       y: this.y
    }
  }
}
```

How can I rewrite the rest of the class to make it work like the previous one? There are some static members and use of external variables in the original file. But I am not sure how to do that correctly in ES6.

Comment: How do you intend to handle `initPack`? Do you want it also to be a "static field" of `Player`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modern way to create static or Class variable for Javascript class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982610/modern-way-to-create-static-or-class-variable-for-javascript-class)

Comment: @4castle That's the problem I want to solve. `initPack` was not a static member but a global variable which was used in somewhere else in the project. Each time I instantiate a `Player` object it will be pushed into the static list and its initial data will be pushed into `initPack`'s player array. Do I have to use an `init` method in the class? That seems a bit odd because now I have to init the class before I can use static members.

Comment: You can put the `Player.list[self.id]` and the `push` statement in the constructor. Just replace `self` with `this`.

Comment: There isn't any syntactic sugar for static properties in ES6. That custom `init` function is a workaround, but notice that it gets called and deleted from the class immediately after the class declaration, so you don't have to worry about initializing the static members later.

Comment: "*`self.update() {`*" appears to be a syntax error

Comment: @Bergi Just typo, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You would put these things just inside the constructor or next to the `class` as you did before.

```
class Player {
  constructor(param) {
    this.id = param.id;
    this.x = param.x;
    this.y = param.y;

    Player.list[this.id] = this;
    initPack.player.push(this.getInitPack());
  }
  update() {
    …
  }
  getInitPack() {
    …
  }
}
Player.list = {};
const initPack = { player: [] };

module.exports = Player;
```

You should however notice that such global singleton storages are an antipattern, and even if you really need them you should better decouple them from the construction.

Comment: Yes I notice that. So I am looking for an OO way for this problem. I don't want to use global variable in a class module.

Comment: Make an extra class for the lists and packs then and give them an `addPlayer` method that either takes a player instance as an argument or creates it. Instantiate the store where you need it (e.g. once per game).