# Access the static property of a javascript class without using an instance of the class

Tags: javascript, class, static

I am trying to access the static properties of a class without using an instance of the class to do so. I tried adapting the method in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript#1535687), but to no avail. All I get is `test.getInstanceId is not a function`

Based on how I am creating the class (below), how can I do this? [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/gt0wd8hp/).

```
test = (function() {
  var currentInstance;

  function test() {
    this.id = 0;
    currentInstance = this;
    // this won 't work
    this.getInstanceId = function() {
      return currentInstance.id;
    }
  }


  test.prototype.setId = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  return test;
})();


var myTest = new test();
myTest.setId(1);
console.log(myTest.id)
console.log(test.getInstanceId());
```

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be `console.log(myTest.getInstanceId())` instead? https://jsfiddle.net/gt0wd8hp/10/

Comment: @Baruch `new test()` will create an instance of the `class` `test`. Defining classes like this allows me to have static variables which I can access from an instance of the class.  `myTest` is an instance of `test`, and in order to be able to use it, I would need to have kept a global reference to it, which I am hoping I don't need to do.

Comment: Yea, I deleted that comment once I realized it made no sense.

Comment: The purpose of using a closure that way is to create "private" properties. If you want them public, then make them public, e.g. `test.currentInstance = ...`. By convention, constructor names start with a capital letter, so *Test* rather than *test*.

Comment: @RobG - Thanks for your help and insight. I've posted an answer with working code for anyone who follows, but if you'd like to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to RobG, the code below works. It makes the variable public by setting it using `test.currentInstance = ...`. Here is [the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/gt0wd8hp/16/).

When inspecting the object `test`, the now public var `currentInstance` seems to "live" outside the `test` function prototype, which I didn't realize was possible.

I have **not** corrected the naming convention which he has pointed out - it should be Test instead of test.

```
test = (function() {
  test.currentInstance = undefined;

  function test() {
    this.id = 0;
    test.currentInstance = this;
  }


  test.prototype.setId = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  return test;
})();



var myTest = new test();
myTest.setId(1);
console.log(myTest.id)
console.log(test.currentInstance.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As my comment suggests, you're using `test.getInstanceId()` instead of `myTest.getInstanceId()`

```
var test = (function() {
  var currentInstance;
  /* This won't work
  function getInstanceId(){
      return currentInstance.id;
  }
  */

  function test() {
    this.id = 0;
    currentInstance = this;
    // this won 't work
    this.getInstanceId = function() {
      return currentInstance.id;
    }
  }


  test.prototype.setId = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  return test;
})();


var myTest = new test();
myTest.setId(1);
console.log(myTest.id)
console.log(myTest.getInstanceId());
```

Fid: https://jsfiddle.net/gt0wd8hp/10/

Comment: myTest is an instance of test, and in order to be able to use it, I would need to have kept a global reference to it. Any way to get at the static without the instance myTest?

Comment: Don't think so. You could probably do something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1535687/554021

Comment: Yes, that was the same link I posted in the question.I am needing to keep my class definition in its current format. If I can't find an outer way to access the static, I'll have to keep a reference to an instance of the class.