# Class variable using Class syntax in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class-variables

I'd like to know if Javascript's `class` syntax support static, or class variables in the following way

```
class MyClass {
  var myVar = 0;

  //I have also tried these combinations of keywords
  static var myVar = 0;
  static myVar = 0;
  this.myVar = 0;
  this.var myVar = 0;
}

MyClass.myVar //0
```

I see that this is possible using the `this` keyword when defining a class with the `function` keyword, but I don't see if it's possible using `class`.  I would hope it is, considering the `class` syntax supports static functions.  I have tried the following.

I do not wish to use the `constructor` method, because then the variable would be an instance variable, and that's not what I'm asking for.

Comment: It doesn't support it yet, there is a proposal, perhaps in ES2017... You can use Babel though.

Comment: Why don't you set it on the `MyClass` itself then? `MyClass.myVar = 0`

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript) will help. Also, @thefourtheye is correct: you can write `MyClass.myVar = 0;` which works just fine.

Comment: You can do this in TypeScript if that's your cup of tea.

Comment: @chazsolo It does not "works just fine" when considering inheritance.

Comment: @torazaburo by all means please, enlighten me - perhaps I've been doing something all along, the consequences of which I'm not aware.

Comment: @thefourtheye with this solution, am I able to allow the static functions of MyClass to manipulate that variable?  After some experimentation, it does not appear to be the case.

Comment: @Csteele5 Please note that it has the limitation mentioned by @torazaburo above. Also, you need to access the variable with the function name, `MyClass.myVar`. I assume you were trying to manipulate them with `this`