# How do I use a static variable in ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm trying to use a static variable in es6. I'd like to declare a static variable `count` in `Animal` class and increase it. However, I couldn't declare a static variable through `static count = 0;`, so I tried another way like this:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
  }

  static increaseCount() {
    this.count += 1;
  }

  static getCount() {
    return this.count;
  }
}

console.log(Animal.increaseCount()); // undefined
console.log(Animal.getCount()); // NaN
```

I expected `console.log(Animal.getCount());` to be `1`, but it doesn't work. 
How do I declare a static variable and modify it by calling a method?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript

Comment: `undefined + 1 = NaN`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

(**Note**: Mutable `static` properties on classes can be problematic when subclasses are involved. See the end of an answer for details on that.)

Your class has no static variables (if by static variable you mean static property). `getCount` returns `NaN` (after you call `increaseCount`) because `Animal` has no `count` property initially. Then `increaseCount` does `undefined + 1` which is `NaN`, and assigns that to `Animal.count`. *Instances* created by `new Animal` have a `count` property initially, but `Animal` itself does not until you call `increaseCount`. `this` within a `static` method refers to the `Animal` class (constructor function) itself (if you call it via `Animal.methodName(...)`).

To give the class a static property, you can declare it with the `static` keyword (now that the class fields proposal¹ has been widely implemented):

```js
class Animal {
    static count = 0;

    static increaseCount() {
        ++this.count;
    }

    static getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }
}

Animal.increaseCount();
console.log(Animal.getCount());
Animal.increaseCount();
console.log(Animal.getCount());
```

If you like, you could make the static member private so it can't be accessed from outside `Animal`:

```js
class Animal {
    static #count = 0;

    static increaseCount() {
        ++this.#count;
    }

    static getCount() {
        return this.#count;
    }
}

Animal.increaseCount();
console.log(Animal.getCount());
Animal.increaseCount();
console.log(Animal.getCount());
```

---

Regarding the caveat above: Using `this` within a static method to refer to the class (constructor function) is a bit tricky if there are subclasses, because for instance, if you had:

```
class Mammal extends Animal {}
```

and then

```
Mammal.increaseCount();
```

`this` within `increaseCount` (which it inherits from `Animal`) refers to `Mammal`, not `Animal`.

```js
class Animal {
    static count = 0;

    static increaseCount() {
        ++this.count;
    }

    static getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }
}

class Mammal extends Animal {
}

console.log(Object.hasOwn(Mammal, "count")); // false
// This call *reads* from `Animal.count` (because `Mammal` doesn't have a
// `count` yet), but *writes* to `Mammal.count`, potentially causing
// confusion.
Mammal.increaseCount();
console.log(Object.hasOwn(Mammal, "count")); // true
console.log(Mammal.getCount()); // 1
// This time, both the read and write use `Mammal.count`
Mammal.increaseCount();
console.log(Mammal.getCount()); // 2
console.log(Animal.getCount()); // 0 - nothing ever wrote to it
```

If you **want** that behavior, use `this`. If you don't, use `Animal` in those `static` methods.

Finally, I'll note that if you make `count` a private field, trying to call `increaseCount` via `Mammal` will fail, because `Mammal` can't write to `Animal.#count`:

```js
class Animal {
    static #count = 0;

    static increaseCount() {
        ++this.#count;
    }

    static getCount() {
        return this.#count;
    }
}

class Mammal extends Animal {
}

Mammal.increaseCount();
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−− TypeError: Cannot read private member #count from an
// object whose class did not declare it
```

---

¹ The *class fields* proposal was an amalgamation of multiple proposals that were initially separate: [Private instance methods and accessors](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods), [Class Public Instance Fields & Private Instance Fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), [Static class fields and private static methods](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features).

Comment: Is it allowed `static count = 0;` in `Animal` class? It causes `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`. I'm using Babel with Webpack.

Comment: @Caesium133 - As I said above, that's part of the [static class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features/) which is currently at Stage 3 of the process (so, it's not in the spec yet, and engines are only just now looking to add it).

Comment: How do you put increaseCount in the constructor of a new Animal? isn't that, ultimately, why people usually want counters on classes? Seems you don't show that case. (tho' i suppose `count` should really be a property of a collection, not the instance-class -- making count a static property of the class is a kind of 'low-budget' collection, eh?

Comment: @johnywhy - Didn't seem to be the OP's use case.

Comment: `static count = 0;` seems to work these days... am I dreaming? however, it is very different than Java's static

Comment: @OhadR - No, you're not dreaming. :-) V8 (in Chrome, Node.js, Brave, Chromium, the new Edge,  etc.) and SpiderMonkey (in Firefox 75+) have both started supporting `static` public fields. Safari is still in progress.

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in other answers, `this.count` refers to *instance* property in `constructor`. In order for *static* property to be initialized, `Animal.count` should be set.

[Class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) provides syntactic sugar for `Animal.count = 0` that is available with transpilers (Babel, etc):

```
class Animal {
  static count = 0;
  ...
}
```

An alternative in ES6 is to use initial values, in this case `Animal.count` initial value doesn't need to be set explicitly, e.g.:

```
class Animal {    
  static increaseCount() {
    this.count = this.getCount() + 1;
  }

  static getCount() {
    return this.count || 0;
  }
}
```

Accessor methods aren't welcome in JavaScript classes - this is what getter/setter descriptors are for:

```
class Animal {    
  static increaseCount() {
    this.count += 1;
  }

  static get count() {
    return this._count || 0;
  }

  static set count(v) {
    this._count = v;
  }
}
```

Static-only class is considered antipattern in JavaScript because a state or other traits that are specific to classes aren't used. In case there should be only one instance, plain object should be used (unless there are other concerns that could benefit from `class`):

```
const animal = {    
  increaseCount() {
    this.count += 1;
  },

  get count() {
    return this._count || 0;
  },

  set count(v) {
    this._count = v;
  }
};
```

Comment: But aren't your getter and setter functions Accessor methods?

Comment: Isn't your getCount an Accessor method?

Comment: Your Animal class with getter and setter returns 0 with: `let b = new Animal;
  console.log(Animal.count);`

Comment: @johnywhy This is expected behaviour. It's static-only class. It's supposed to be used like `Animal.increaseCount(); console.log(Animal.count === 1)`. `getCount` is called accessor method, `count` defined by a pair of `get` and `set` is called accessor descriptor.

Comment: I would say to be more useful, your class with get/set should increment itself when a new instance is created. Your final object style doesn't actually return the value of _count, if _count == 0. It returns 0 when _count is actually undefined. It's a false result. I'd consider that a bug. Since that object requires initializing count to 0 externally, it seems no different than just using a variable. Is an object which acts no different than a variable considered an anti-pattern?

Comment: @johnywhy Thanks for noticing, there was a typo, it should be this.count and not this._count in increaseCount and other members besides get/set count. `get count() { return this._count || 0 }` is mostly the same as `_count: 0, get count() { return this._count }`. I prefer `|| 0` because it takes less chars to type and also fixes some invalid values, could be changed to `this._count = +v || 0` in `set` instead for better value conditioning. It depends on the case if it's an antipattern. An object can be extended and is more testable. And its behaviour can be changed any time if needed

Answer (score 4):

Static class-side properties and prototype data properties must be defined outside of the ClassBody declaration.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

```js
class Animal {

  static increaseCount() {
    Animal.count += 1;
  }

  static getCount() {
    return Animal.count;
  }
}

Animal.count = 0;

Animal.increaseCount();
console.log(Animal.getCount()); // undefined
```

Comment: It's ok but the last code line return 1 , not undefined. It could be misleading for newbie

Comment: Today you don't have to declare it outside anymore

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate static variables with static getter and setter

```
 export class MyClass {
  static get variable() {
    return this.foo;
  }

  static set variable(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

And use it like this

```
  MyClass.variable = 'bar';
  console.log(MyClass.variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a static variable, set it on the object Animal itself. As of now in Javascript you cannot directly declare static properties inside classes like you can declare static methods.

```
class Animal {
    constructor() {
    }

    static increaseCount() {
        this.count += 1;
    }

    static getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }
}
Animal.count = 0;
console.log(Animal.increaseCount());
console.log(Animal.getCount());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use closures to simulate static variables

```js
const Animal= (() => {
    let count= 0;

    class Animal {
        constructor() {}

        static increaseCount() {
            count += 1;
        }

        static getCount() {
            return count;
        }
    }

    return Animal;
})();

console.log(Animal.getCount());
Animal.increaseCount();
console.log(Animal.getCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have incremential ids:

```
 constructor() {
    super(template);
    if (typeof MyClass.nextId == 'undefined') {
    MyClass.nextId = 0;
    }
    this._id = `${MyClass.nextId++}`;
 }
```