# How to clone a Javascript class

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, class

During unit testing, I want to Mock class Foo with a class called Bar.
I have to change a propriety in the class Foo for the test.

This is what I tried. 
It should print:

Foo

Bar

```js
class Foo {
  id = 'foo'
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.id)
  }
}
const Bar = { ...Foo }
Bar.prototype.id = 'Bar'
new Foo()
new Bar()
```

I get instead:

```
error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined
```

I know I can achieve this by creating a new class Bar extends Foo but is there other possible solutions ?

Comment: not really sure what you're trying to do, but you're probably trying to use a setter to update a class's property. Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript/45863870 Or just look up on what classes are supposed to do altogether https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes.

Comment: When you "copy" Foo using spread syntax, it only copies enumerable properties. Foo's *prototype* property is not enumerable so isn't copied. *Bar* doesn't have a public *prototype* property, so trying to assign to it is a TypeError. You can't create a constructor this way: *Bar* is a plain object, constructors must be functions.

Comment: BTW, [public field declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Defining_classes) (e.g. `id = 'foo'`) are experimental and will fail in some browsers at least.

Answer (score 2):

Object Spread `{...o}` only considers *enumerable* properties.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Examples) (emphasis mine):

> Spread in object literals
>   The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (ES2018) added spread properties to object literals. It copies own **enumerable** properties from a provided object onto a new object.

The `prototype` property of classes and function is not enumerable. Therefore, in `const Bar = {...Foo}`, `Bar` will not have a `prototype` property. That is precisely why you get

```
error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined
```

Now, to get the code closer to what you want, you *could* write

```
const Bar = {...Foo, prototype: Foo.prototype};
```

However, now `Bar` will behave differently from `Foo` because *its* `prototype` property *will* be enumerable.

So we *could* revise this and write

```
const Bar = {...Foo};
Object.defineProperty(Bar, 'prototype', {value: Foo.protoype, enumerable: false});
// `enumerable` defaults to `false` using this API, just being explicit for exposition.
```

However, your next statement, `new B` will still fail because `B` is still not a class object or a function object and therefore cannot be used with the new operator.

Without more context it is difficult to tell why you actually want to do this.

The most straightforward approach would be to write the following

```
class Foo {
  id = 'Foo';
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.id);
  }
}
class Bar extends Foo {
  id = 'Bar';
}
new Foo() // logs 'Foo'
new Bar() // logs 'Bar'
```

If you would like to avoid using inheritance, there are other alternatives, but it is not clear which ones are appropriate because the question lacks sufficient context to determine this. For example, if you only want to mock objects *created* via `new Foo`, then you could mock them trivially using a helper function that just overwrites the property with the test value, if you want to mock `Foo` itself, that is to say the class object, then the alternatives would be different.

Answer (score 1):

Instance properties in NodeJS and Babel are not actually set to the prototype. They are set in the constructor.

Check this:

```
class Foo {
  id = 1
}

new Foo().hasOwnProperty('id') // => true
```

An object will only lookup a property on its prototype if it's not defined within itself, so overriding the prototype won't work.

If you want to avoid `class` syntax, you could do something like this:

```
function Bar() {
  const o = new Foo()
  o.id = 'bar'
  return o
}

new Bar().id // => 'bar'
```